# Existence of an infinitely differentiable function $ f $ with $ {f^{(n)}}(0) = 0 $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

How can one show that there exists an infinitely differentiable function $ f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ such that $ {f^{(n)}}(0) = 0 $ but $ f^{(n)} \not\equiv 0 $ for all $ n \in \mathbb{N} $?

Answer (score 6):

The function $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ is a canonical such example.

Comment: Inductively, for any $n\in\mathbb N$ one can prove $f^{(n)}(x)=p(x)e^{-1/x^2}$ for some rational function $p(x)$. Now, taking the limit $x\to 0$ gives $f^{(n)}(0)=0$.

Answer (score 6):

The function $f$ given by
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\exp\left(-1/x\right),\quad&x>0,\\
0,&x\leq 0
\end{cases}
$$
has derivatives of all orders that satisfy $f^{(n)}(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $n\in\mathbb N$. See e.g. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function) and/or this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37241/proving-a-function-is-infinitely-differentiable).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Cauchy gave it as an example for a non-analytical function.