# Proving $e^{1/x}$ is infinitely differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

I came across this problem awhile ago: [Proving a function is infinitely differentiable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37241/proving-a-function-is-infinitely-differentiable). It is about proving that $f$ is infinitely differentiable for $f=0, x\leq 0$ and $f=e^{-1/x}$ for $x>0$.

It is stated "Similarly, when x is greater than zero the function is infinitely differentiable, by the properties of the exponential function." I don't understand how this statement is proven. How does one use properties of $e^x$ to show this?

Comment: What is $f(0)$?

Answer (score 2):

Your question concerns the region $x>0$. I claim that
$$f^{(n)}(x)= e^{-1/x}\>p_n(1/x)\qquad(x>0, \ n\geq0)\ ,\tag{1}$$
where $p_n(1/x)$ is a polynomial of degree $2n$ in ${1\over x}$. This is  true for $n=0$, by definition of $f$. We therefore have to compute
$$f^{(n+1)}(x)=e^{-1/x}\>{1\over x^2}\bigl(p_n(1/x)-p_n'(1/x)\bigr)\>\qquad(x>0, \ n\geq0)\ .$$
Here the RHS is $e^{-1/x}$ times a polynomial in ${1\over x}$ of degree $2(n+1)$.

This shows that $f$ has derivatives of all orders $n\geq0$ on ${\mathbb R}_{>0}$.

Comment: @nicomezi: The question was about "the $x$ that are greater than zero".

Comment: You are right. The first paragraph seems just to be some background ... It is not clear at all to me what this question is about ....

Answer (score 0):

Your $f$ is the composition of two infinitely differentiable functions ($e^x$ and $-1/x$, for $x>0$) and therefore infinitely differentiable itself.

Comment: Obviously, but not required here.

Comment: The question seems to be asking differentiability for positive values. I agree with you that, anyway, the interesting part is another.