# Taylor series of $e^{-1/x}$

Tags: integration, taylor-expansion, improper-integrals, euler-lagrange-equation, euler-maclaurin

Does the integral converge?
$$\int_0^\infty (1-e^{-1/x})\,\Bbb dx$$

Idea: First I tried to expand the $e^{-1/x}$ using the Maclaurin series and evaluated the integral, but it was not a good result and then I realized the result is not correct, because we cannot expand $e^{-1/x}$ by the Maclaurin series (because all derivatives of $e^{-1/x}$ at $x=0$ are zero but $e^{-1/x}$ is not a zero function so the approximate centered at $0$ doesn’t work).

We can find the Taylor series expansion of $e^{-1/x}$ centered at some point (like $x=1$). According to that, the integral is divergent. I just want to know

1. Is my understanding correct? and
2. Can we expand $e^{-1/x}$ by the Taylor series centered at some point (except zero) even the function is non-analytic?

And is this the right way to evaluate this kind of integral? It will be a great pleasure to me if someone can give a little explanation.

Comment: Please [don't use `\frac` in exponents or limits of integrals](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189). It looks bad and confusing, and it rarely appears in professional mathematics typesetting.

Comment: Use $e^{-1/x}$ instead, or $\exp\big(-\frac{1}{x}\big)$.

Comment: Ohh I am so sorry I will keep it in my mind

Comment: You integral diverges because for $x$ high enough $1-e^{1/x} \sim 1$

Comment: The integrand goes to zero

Comment: You should be able to show that for $x > 1$ you have $\frac{0.63212}x \le (1-e^{-{1}/{x}}) \le \frac1x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we have $x\in[0,\infty)$ we can see that:
$$x\to0^+,\frac1x\to+\infty\therefore e^{-1/x}\to0$$
so for small values of $x$, $1-e^{-1/x}\approx 1$. Now if we look at large values of $x$:
$$x\to+\infty,\frac1x\to0^+\therefore e^{-1/x}\to1$$
and so for large values of $x$, $1-e^{-1/x}\to0$. However,
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^n}dx$$
only converges for $n>1$ so for your integral to converge you need to show that your function tends to zero faster than $1/x$, which it does not so the integral will diverge

Comment: After the word However I did not understand why you take that integral $\int_{1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^n}dx$

Comment: @NuwanPriyankara this is a standard integral for which values are known and we can use it as a comparison

Comment: Yes, I know that so $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x}$ diverges but how do we compare it to this, here we need to get the idea of $e^{-1/x}$ on $[1,\infty)$ now. please explain little bit

Comment: Did you expand $1−e^{−1/x}=\frac{1}{x}−\frac{1}{2x^2}+ ...$ and did you use the Laurent series?

Answer (score 3):

As EDX hoped to write: $1-e^{-1/x} \sim 1/x$, so the integral is divergent.

Comment: Thanks for corrective

Answer (score 2):

Your integral diverges because $$1-e^{-1/x} \sim 1/x$$ for $x$ high enough.

Comment: $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}1-e^{-1/x} = 1-e^{0} = 0$?

Comment: Right ! I corrected it !

Comment: How it tends to $1/x$?

Comment: Taylor Young is enough  !

Comment: Sorry what is Taylor Young ?

Comment: It is the asymptotic development proposed by Varun Vejalla

Answer (score 1):

You have that $$e^{x}=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^3)$$

so $$1-e^{-1/x} = \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}-O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right) < \frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2x^2}$$

And because $\int_1^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2x^2}\right) dx$ diverges, $\int_1^{\infty}\left(1-e^{-1/x}\right)dx$ will diverge as well.

Edit: I dropped the integral from $0$ to $1$ because the integrand is bounded by $1$, so it is convergent for that interval.

Comment: Here you use Maclaurin series, as I mentioned in the original problem can we use Maclaurin series expansion?

Comment: You can't use the Maclaurin series for $e^{-1/x}$ as is, but you can use the Laurent series expansion (which I did in my question).

Comment: Ok got it, like this situation when we are using Laurent series do we need to consider or specify any condition to apply (because the Laurent series is a series that represent a complex function f(z) as a series and a Laurent series includes terms with negative as well as non-negative powers of z.) ?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't like to give an answer directly here. I have answered several questions related to the function $\textrm{e}^{x^\alpha}$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ several times. However, I would like to list several references in which you can find the answer and more.

1. https://qifeng618.wordpress.com/2018/05/10/some-papers-related-to-the-function-e1-x-and-the-lah-numbers/
2. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405015
3. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4262516/945479
4. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4262498/945479
5. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4262657/945479
6. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4263059/945479
7. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4263072/945479
8. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4263062/945479