# $n$th derivative of $e^{ax^m}$

Tags: combinatorics, derivatives, power-series, taylor-expansion

> I am seeking an explicit expression for the $n$th derivative of $e^{ax^m}$.

To achieve this I consider the $n$th coefficient of the Taylor series with $t\rightarrow 0$.
\begin{align}
    e^{a(x+t)^m} &= \sum^\infty_{n=0}\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{d^n}{dt^n}e^{a(x+t)^m}\frac{t^n}{n!}\\
    &=\sum^\infty_{n=0}\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{d^n}{dt^n}e^{a\left[\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}x^kt^{m-k}\right]}\frac{t^n}{n!}\\
    &=e^{ax^m}\sum^\infty_{n=0}\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{d^n}{dt^n}e^{a\sum\limits_{k=0}^{m-1}\binom{m-1}{k}x^kt^{m-k-1}}\frac{t^n}{n!}
\end{align}
But we can also consider the left hand side as
\begin{align}
e^{a(x+t)^m} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(a(x+t)^m)^k}{k!}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{mk}\binom{mk}{j}x^{j}t^{mk-j}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{a^k}{k!}x^{mk}\sum_{j=0}^{mk-1}\binom{mk-1}{j}x^{j}t^{mk-1-j}\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(ax^m)^k}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{mk-1}\frac{(mk-1)!}{j!(mk-1-j)!}x^{j}t^{mk-1-j}
\end{align}
Although I can't really take it further. My next step would be to extract the $n$th coefficient and, upon comparison to the first formula, obtain an expression for the $n$th derivative. When $m=2$ we obtain the Hermite polynomials. Related to

[$n$th derivative of $e^{1/x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18284/nth-derivative-of-e1-x)

[Find an expression for the $n$-th derivative of $f(x)=e^{x^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193702/find-an-expression-for-the-n-th-derivative-of-fx-ex2?noredirect=1&lq=1)

and links therein. With thanks to BillyJoe from the comments, Wolfram gives
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{ax^m}=e^{ax^m}x^{-n}\sum^n_{k=0}\sum^k_{j=0}\frac{(-1)^j(ax^m)^k(1-jm+km-n)_n}{j!(k-j)!}
\end{equation}

I have also seen that this is equivalent to n exponent rial Riordan array, $B_m=[1,(1+x)^m+1]$.
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^n}{dx^n}e^{ax^m}=\left( \sum_{k\in \mathbb Z}b_{n,k;m}(ax)^{km-n}\right)e^{ax^m}
\end{equation}

Comment: So you obtained $
e^{a(x^m  - 1)}  = e^{a(x^m  - 1)} e^{a(x + t)^{m - 1} }  \Leftrightarrow 1 = e^{a(x + t)^{m - 1} } $. It is a bit suspicious to me...

Comment: @Gary yes, I see your point, I will add another line to help spot any errors I have made. Is that more clear?

Comment: The left-hand side of your very first series of computations should be $
e^{a((x + t)^m  - 1)} $ and not $e^{a(x^m-1)}$, because that is the function of $t$ you expand into a Taylor series about $0$. Regarding you main question, I would use Faà di Bruno's formula. I do not think there is a nicer way in general.

Comment: [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n-th+derivative+of+e%5E%28a*x%5Em%29) is what WolframAlpha founds. Multiply that result by $e^{-a}$.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments, I will update the question with these!

Comment: You might consider starting with $e^{a(x^m-1)}=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} (1/j!)[a(x^m-1)]^j$

Comment: In terms of the Bell polynomials,
$$\frac {d^n} {d x^n} e^{a x^m} =
e^{a x^m} B_n {\left(
\frac d {dx} (a x^m), \frac {d^2} {dx^2} (a x^m), \ldots \right)},
\quad m \in \mathbb C.$$
In terms of the Fox-Wright function,
$$\frac {d^n} {d x^n} e^{a x^m} =
\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac {d^n} {d x^n} \frac {(a x^m)^k} {k!} =
x^{-n} {_1 \hspace {-1.5 px} \Psi_1} {\left(
 a x^m \middle| {(1, m) \atop (1 - n, m)} \right)},
\quad m \in \mathbb R^+.$$

Comment: For integer $m$, there is a hypergeometric $_pF_p$ solution,  the cases are for $n>m$ and $m<n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the Faa di Bruno formula
\begin{equation}\label{Bruno-Bell-Polynomial}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}t^n}f\circ h(t)
=\sum_{k=0}^nf^{(k)}(h(t)) B_{n,k}\bigl(h'(t),h''(t),\dotsc,h^{(n-k+1)}(t)\bigr), \quad n\ge0,
\end{equation}
we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}x^n}\operatorname{e}^{ax^m}&=
\sum_{k=0}^n \operatorname{e}^{ax^m} B_{n,k}(a\langle m\rangle_1x^{m-1},a\langle m\rangle_2 x^{m-2},\dotsc, a\langle m\rangle_{n-k+1}x^{m-(n-k+1)})\\
&=\operatorname{e}^{ax^m}\sum_{k=0}^n a^k x^{mk-n} B_{n,k}(\langle m\rangle_1, \langle m\rangle_2,\dotsc,\langle m\rangle_{n-k+1})\\
&=\frac{\operatorname{e}^{ax^m}}{x^n}\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k\frac{a^k x^{mk}}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k}(-1)^{\ell}\binom{k}{\ell}\langle m\ell\rangle_n,
\end{align*}
where we used the formulas
\begin{gather}
\langle z\rangle_n=
\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(z-k)=
\begin{cases}
z(z-1)\dotsm(z-n+1), & n\in\mathbb{N};\\
1,& n=0,
\end{cases}\\
B_{n,k}\bigl(\alpha\beta x_1,\alpha \beta^2x_2,\dotsc,\alpha \beta^{n-k+1}x_{n-k+1}\bigr)
=\alpha^k\beta^n B_{n,k}(x_1,x_2,\dotsc,x_{n-k+1}),\\
B_{n,k}(\langle\alpha\rangle_1, \langle\alpha\rangle_2, \dotsc,\langle\alpha\rangle_{n-k+1})
=\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k}(-1)^{\ell}\binom{k}{\ell}\langle\alpha\ell\rangle_n.
\end{gather}

References

1. Feng Qi, *Taylor's series expansions for real powers of two functions containing squares of inverse cosine function, closed-form formula for specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representations for real powers of Pi*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 710--736; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0157.
2. Wei-Shih Du, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Several recursive and closed-form formulas for some specific values of partial Bell polynomials*, Advances in the Theory of Nonlinear Analysis and its Applications **6** (2022), no. 4, 528--537; available online at https://doi.org/10.31197/atnaa.1170948.
3. Bai-Ni Guo, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Maclaurin's series expansions for positive integer powers of inverse (hyperbolic) sine and tangent functions, closed-form formula of specific partial Bell polynomials, and series representation of generalized logsine function*, Applicable Analysis and Discrete Mathematics **16** (2022), no. 2, 427--466; available online at https://doi.org/10.2298/AADM210401017G.
4. Siqintuya Jin, Bai-Ni Guo, and Feng Qi, *Partial Bell polynomials, falling and rising factorials, Stirling numbers, and combinatorial identities*, Computer Modeling in Engineering & Sciences **132** (2022), no. 3, 781--799; available online at https://doi.org/10.32604/cmes.2022.019941.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Experimentally, the expression is of the form

$$(e^{x^m})^{(n)}=P_{mn}(x^m)x^{(-n)\bmod m}e^{x^m}$$ where $P_{mn}$ is a polynomial of degree $n-\left\lfloor\dfrac nm\right\rfloor$. You can arrange the coefficients in a triangular table, with a recurrence relation between the rows.

$$P_{m.n+1}x^{(-n-1)\bmod m}=\\mx^{m-1}(P'_{mn}(x^m)+P_{mn}(x^m))x^{(-n)\bmod m}+((-n)\bmod m)P_{mn}(x^m)x^{(-n)\bmod m-1}$$

which simplifies differently when $m|n$ or not.